# how to load web browser in a defined height&width?

Tags: android, xml

I want to load browser in an activity and  i want to have some text on top and  one button at bottom
my code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bac">
    <WebView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/webView1" android:layout_x="0dp" android:layout_y="92dp" android:layout_height="300dp"></WebView>
    <Button android:id="@+id/frobeproceedbutton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="proceed" android:layout_x="107dp" android:layout_y="411dp"></Button>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="if you authorize the access then click proceed" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_x="-2dp" android:layout_y="24dp"></TextView>


</AbsoluteLayout>
```

the activity is displayed with textview, webview and a button but the browser not fitting in the defined webview layout. general browser is launching

can any one suggest an approach . any help can be appreciated.

Thanks,
HAriprasad Reddy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are employing AbsoluteLayout but try this and see if this is working for you:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="if you authorize the access then click proceed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_x="-2dp" android:layout_y="24dp"></TextView>
    <WebView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_x="0dp" android:layout_y="92dp" android:layout_height="300dp"></WebView>
    <Button android:id="@+id/frobeproceedbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="proceed" android:layout_x="107dp" android:layout_y="411dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```